# No combo filter to show all

Tags: combobox

This is my first time here.

I have almost no experience in ASP bu tI need to develop a small site linked to an access database in order to load data.

So, in my site I've got two combobox or if you prefer List/Menu controls.

It's working ok, I mean, if I choose an option in each combox it filter.

What I need to to have an option in each combobox to not filter, such like an option saying ALL, so if I choose the option ALL in one combobox it would show all records.

I hope I was clear.

Please help.

Thanks.
Marco

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP 3.0, you simply add a new item:

```
<select name="mycombo">
<option value="0">All</option>
...
</select>
```

Check for the item 0 and dont act on it.

```
If you are usng .NET
<asp:DropDownList id="mycombo" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem value="0" Text="All" />
...
</asp:DropDownlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you choose All then remove the filter criteria and show all records.

First of all add the option All to your combo box at a specified index. When the combo values is changed check for that index and if it is the index of 'All' then remove the filter criteria applied and show full records.